# Python dir builtins not consistent

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to check programmatically if print is a built-in Python funcion.

Using Python 3.4.x when querying `dir(__builtins__)` from the Python command line I get what I'm looking for:

```
['ArithmeticError', 'AssertionError', ..... , 'pow', 'print' ... ]
```

But when using it in a .py file:

```
import sys

def foo:
   print(dir(__builtins__))
```

The call returns:

```
 ['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__',
 '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__',
 '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__',
 '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'clear', 'copy',
 'fromkeys', 'get', 'items', 'keys', 'pop', 'popitem', 'setdefault',
 'update', 'values']
```

I haven't redefined `__builtins__` at any point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting the [`builtins` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html):

> As an implementation detail, most modules have the name `__builtins__` made available as part of their globals. The value of `__builtins__` is normally either this module or the value of this module’s `__dict__` attribute. Since this is an implementation detail, it may not be used by alternate implementations of Python.

In the command prompt, you are looking at the module object, vs. the `__dict__` object when running the code in a python file. The `dir()` of a dictionary is rather different from `dir()` on a module object.

Rather than look at `__builtins__`, use the `builtins` module:

```
import builtins

hasattr(builtins, 'print')
```